# Free local pointer to global pointer array in ansi c

Tags: arrays, pointers, global, ansi-c

I just wonna ask do I need free local ptr in function in in this case:

```c
char *ptr_array[];

void fnx(...) {

char *local_ptr = &ptr_array[0];

}
```

Comment: It depends. Can't tell without a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```c
const char *array[]={"abcd", "abcd",...}

void getAddr(char **addr); // getting address of specify element in tab;
void fnx(...) {
  char *temp_ptr;
  getAddr(&temp_ptr); //i find here adress what i need in this moment
}
```